# Can I sum an EntityFramework Navigation column in my DataGridView

Tags: entity-framework-4, datagridview, asp.net-4.0

I have two tables/entities, event and eventRegistrations. I have a gridview showing events, but I would like it to have a column that sums eventRegistrations.SomeNumber.

I can get a count of eventRegistrations using the navigation object.

How can I get the sum?

Comment: So, I created a method, `GetSum(object _eventReg)` pass it the Navigation from the grid view like so:  <%# GetSum(Eval("EventRegistrations")) %> and the object is type `Generic.List(of EventRegistrations)`. I then redo the method 'GetSum(List<EventRegistration> _eventReg)` but that fails. _CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'EventRegManager._Default.GetRegSum(System.Collections.Generic.List<FormRouterData.EventRegistration>)' has some invalid arguments_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handled it like this:

`public string GetRegSum(object _eventReg)

        {

        System.Collections.Generic.List<FormRouterData.family_fishing_reg> theseRegs = (System.Collections.Generic.List<FormRouterData.family_fishing_reg>)_eventReg;

            var sum = theseRegs.Sum(er => int.Parse(er.num_group));

            if (sum == 0) { return string.Empty; }

            else { return sum.ToString(); }

        }`

Answer (score 0):

If you can count the event registrations with `event.EventRegistrations.Count()` you should be able to get the sum using the LINQ `Sum` extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```cs
var sum = event.EventRegistrations.Sum(er => er.SomeNumber);
```

Comment: So, that looks like I should put the code in the GridView.OnDataBind event? Or is there a way to put that in the markup?

Comment: @MKenyonII: I don't know, I'm not really familiar with WebForms anymore. I remember that there is an option to create custom columns and fill them `Eval`, perhaps this might work. How do you bind the `Count`? I'd expect that binding the `Sum` works the same way.